# Coroutine doesn't stop when the service containing it stops

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, foreground-service

I have a foreground service that changes wallpapers with a delay, so I'm using coroutines inside of it,I call it from another class with startService(Intent(this,MySerivce::class.java)) but when I stop it with stopService(Intent(this,MySerivce::class.java)), only functions on main thread stop (like showNotification()), here's my code:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
val externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
    if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){


    val root=getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath
        val myDir = File("$root/saved_images")
        val list = myDir.listFiles()
        if (myDir.exists()&&list.size>=2){
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val time = intent?.getIntExtra("TIME",0)
                if (time != null) {
                    manageWallpapers(list,time)
                }

            }
        }}

    
    showNotification()
    
    return START_STICKY
}
}
```

> and here's manageWallpapers function

```
private suspend fun manageWallpapers(list: Array<File>?, time:Int){

    while (true){
        if (list != null) {
            for (image in list){

                setWallpaper(image)
                delay(time.toLong())
                
            }
        }

    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to keep a reference to the job returned by `launch` and call `cancel()` on it when your service is stopped.

```
private var job: Job? = null

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
val externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
    if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){


    val root=getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath
        val myDir = File("$root/saved_images")
        val list = myDir.listFiles()
        if (myDir.exists()&&list.size>=2){
            job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {   // HERE
                val time = intent?.getIntExtra("TIME",0)
                if (time != null) {
                    manageWallpapers(list,time)
                }

            }
        }}

    
    showNotification()
    
    return START_STICKY
}
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = null
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Another option is to keep a reference to your `CoroutineScope` and call `cancel` on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you subclass from LifecycleService, you can use `lifecycleScope` to launch your coroutine, so it will be cancelled automatically when the service stops.

`build.gradle`:

```groovy
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.3.1'
```

In your service, a subclass of `LifecycleService`:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val time = intent?.getIntExtra("TIME",0)
    if (time != null) {
        manageWallpapers(list,time)
    }
}
```

There's no need to specify Dispatchers.IO, since you are only calling a suspend function, not a blocking function.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind **No need to use Dispatchers.IO since you are calling a suspending function** , you can write suspending function to do `IO` or `CPU` intensive task. Choosing the correct `Dispatcher` is important

Comment: @mightyWOZ A properly composed suspend function never blocks. If your suspend function does a CPU intensive task without wrapping it in something like `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` then you are breaking the convention that suspend functions should never be blocking functions.

Comment: Here’s an article on it from the lead developer of coroutines. Note the section titled *Suspending convention*. https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but if I have a coroutine which performs n network calls and 1 CPU intensive task, why should I use `withContext` on each function that perform a network call, since its already suspending (using suspendCoroutine). I would rather specify the `Dispatcher` on Coroutine making all network calls execute on IO and then use `withContext` on single function that has to be executed on Default `Dispatcher`

Comment: Just like any other properly composed suspend function, suspendCoroutine doesn’t block its caller so it’s pointless to specify a dispatcher to call it. The background work is done in the network API’s own thread pool. And even if you were going to call 10 CPU bound blocking functions and one IO blocking function, you should just wrap the whole thing in one `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)` and a second inner `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` for the one exception. But to avoid the nesting, you could break it out into its own suspend function.

Comment: Implicit continuation is invoked on the dispatcher's thread.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn’t be calling blocking code in the lambda you pass to `suspendCoroutine`. Asynchronous callback-based code is fine.